# Whats the equation to calculate the area under the curve of a normal distribution, given an upper and lower standard deviation?

Tags: normal-distribution

Lets say I want to find out the area under the graph of normal distribution curve, between X1=standard deviation of -0.5 and X2 = standard deviation of 0.5. Is there a formula for this?

Case study: find the percentage chance of a stock remaining within +0.5 and -0.5 standard deviations within one trading day, given the daily implied volatility of that stock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply the integral of the pdf from -0.5 to 0.5 (scaled to the SD of the distribution), also known as the **cumulative distribution function** or **cdf**.  The `cdf(x)` function is indicated on the following wikipedia link: [Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

The normal cdf(x) function computes the integral on [-Infinity, x], so to compute on your interval [x1,x2], is simply `cdf(x2) - cdf(x1)`.

So if you meant [-.5, +.5] SDs,then would evaluate `cdf(0.5*sd) - cdf(-0.5*sd)`.

Comment: I should note that the above assumes the mean is 0.  If not 0 then add the mean in the arguments for the cdf.

Comment: ... and for anything finance related, the time series is never stationary, and this technique is only relevant to stationary time series.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the CDF is listed in the book "The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas - 2nd. Edition - Espan Gaarder Haug, Ph.D (McGraw-Hill, 2006, ISBN 9780071389976)".

Comment: You can also find implementations in QuantLib and many other open source packages.